# How to manage Update and Delete Occurance in scheduler?

Tags: c#, winforms, calendar, devexpress-windows-ui

I am using Dev Express Scheduler control. I can insert and update Normal appointment. I use database to store and retrieve information of appointment.

But I don't know how to manage Delete or Update single occurrence. When I delete single occurrence, it call Deleting and Inserting event.

I don't get why it call Insert event when I delete single occurrence of appointment.

Can anybody explain me How delete occurrence mechanism work in Database?

Comment: refer this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/591271/A-Simple-Scheduler-in-Csharp

Comment: Thank you. But I am using Devexpress Scheduler control.